# Getting Null Back from Method Call

Tags: wcf

Ok, let me first state some facts:

1. This is a web service that has been working.  There are several .svc endpoints all of which worked.  Right now though there's one that is not, meaning I can make method calls to it when I consume the service through another project but I keep getting null back as a result.
2. The code for the methods in this service that continually sends back null HAS NOT CHANGED
3. I did mess around with the endpoint configuration pointing it to a couple different servers.  I tried the original server it was pointed to also.  No matter what I can update the service fine but even if I set it back to the old endpoint path, I still get null back from my unit tests when testing calls to this service.  The unit tests are running in the project that's consuming the service of course
4. I've checked the app.config and web.config for the service itself.  As far as I can see everything looks fine...but again I'm new to WCF

I know this is pretty general but I'm looking for some guidance on where to start looking to see why I'm getting null back all of a sudden.  The stored proc behind these methods have not changed. Again these method calls were working at some point in time in the past week but now it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is very general, but a few things to try...

1. Try updating your service reference to ensure you have the most recent version of your proxy objects
2. Have you tried debugging inside your service and seeing if the expected return value is being returned from the service prior to the client getting it?
3. Do you catch all exceptions in the service and then return a result object or do you let exceptions fall through?  If you let them fall through, the WCF channel might be getting faulted.
4. Try using Fiddler and seeing if the endpoints you *think* should be getting called are and if the response object is indeed null.
5. Use an old-school trick and write the result to a file on the server just before you return to the client.  This will help you know whether or not it is a server-to-client serialization issue.  You may even need to write to file right as the service gets the call to make sure your client is connecting.

What you really need to do is start by debugging inside your service and stepping through the code there.  Make absolutely certain the SPROC is returning what you expect and then there isn't an environmental bug introduced.

Comment: #2 I've got unit tests that were there already inside the actual service solution and they now fail.  Earlier they were not failing.  They are failing with null coming back from the unit test on method calls for that service.

Comment: #3 I'm new to this team but they send back a custom status out object to send back the status of the call...

Comment: #4 good idea, let me try that.  I was also told to try out the WCF Test Client to do sort of that also...and to test calls?

Comment: Yes, the WCF Test Client will work too.  That will take out your client variable.  I wonder if the client isn't able to connect to the server to begin with.  How are you setting the endpoint address?  Do you reference the name variable in the app XML or do you programatically set the Endpoint address?

Comment: Also, just old-school approach, write the result to a file on the server before returning to the client.  That will definitely tell you if it is a sever-to-client serialization issue or something else.

Answer (score 1):

When you have weird problems with WCF, the fist thing to do it configure WCF tracing. It's a very powerful tool. You can even see the content of messages.

Here is the official doc on this: [Configuring WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: Yea I did that a while back but it hasn't been much help for this issue.